# How to calculate daily returns of multiple products in R

Tags: r, quantmod

I have a dataset like the following which contains 46 products price history from 2014-5-1 to 2014-11-30:

```
prodid      price        date
19119665    27.89999962 11/25/2014
19119665    27.89999962 11/25/2014
19119665    26.89999962 11/27/2014
19119665    26.89999962 11/28/2014
19119665    26.89999962 11/30/2014
19141710    19.89999962 5/1/2014
19141710    19.89999962 5/1/2014
19141710    19.89999962 5/1/2014
```

And I want to treat each product as a stock and calculate the daily price changes of these products across time.

I have thought of the following code using quantmod:

```
 periodReturn(data,period='daily',subset='prodid')
```

but it seems that this code is not doing what it should be doing. I am getting the following error:

```
Error in try.xts(x) : 
Error in as.POSIXlt.character(x, tz, ...):character string is not in standard unambiguous format
```

Would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that there is one way to achieve what you are asking. Here is my approach with `dplyr`.

```
 dat %>% mutate(perx = price / lag(dat$price) - 1)
    prodid price       date        perx
1 19119665  27.9 11/25/2014          NA
2 19119665  27.9 11/25/2014  0.00000000
3 19119665  26.9 11/27/2014 -0.03584229
4 19119665  26.9 11/28/2014  0.00000000
5 19119665  26.9 11/30/2014  0.00000000
6 19141710  19.9   5/1/2014 -0.26022305
7 19141710  19.9   5/1/2014  0.00000000
8 19141710  19.9   5/1/2014  0.00000000
```

Comment: @user227710 intraday changes?